# Should I always fully qualify method and classes in VBA

Tags: vba

The question I have is: **Should I always fully qualify methods and classes in VBA?**

---

This is  a unit test which checks wherever a given collection is sorted or not after using `Lapis.CollectionExt.Sort` method.

- `Lapis` is the name of my addin which I'm developing.
- `ExUnit` and `CollectionExt` are names of standard modules.
- `GetSig` method creates a full signature (name of the module and method name) of currently executing method.

**Fully qualified methods and objects**

```vb
Private Sub SortTest()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Const MethodName = "SortTest"

    ' Act
    Dim Actual As VBA.Collection
    Set Actual = Lapis.CollectionExt.Sort(Lapis.CollectionExt.Make(3, 2, 1), New Lapis.LongComparer)

    ' Assert
    Dim Expected As VBA.Collection: Set Expected = Lapis.CollectionExt.Make(1, 2, 3)
    Lapis.ExUnit.AreEqualSets Expected, Actual, New Lapis.LongEqualityComparer, GetSig(MethodName)

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Lapis.ExUnit.TestFailRunTime GetSig(MethodName)

End Sub
```

**Minimally qualified methods and objects**

```vb
Private Sub SortTest()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Const MethodName = "SortTest"

    ' Act
    Dim Actual As Collection
    Set Actual = CollectionExt.Sort(CollectionExt.Make(3, 2, 1), New LongComparer)

    ' Assert
    Dim Expected As Collection: Set Expected = CollectionExt.Make(1, 2, 3)
    ExUnit.AreEqualSets Expected, Actual, New LongEqualityComparer, GetSig(MethodName)

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    ExUnit.TestFailRunTime GetSig(MethodName)

End Sub
```

I feel like always fully qualifying names can increase a "code-noise" within code base and as a consequence, make code harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever need to do it at all with your own code.

Name your classes/methods descriptively so they avoid collisions. Avoid generic names.

So, your CollectionExt I'd be inclined to name LapisCollection instead. It's only 2 chars more and gives you the full origin of the class without the qualification. The only time you're ever going to have to qualify that is if someone else writes a module/addin called "Lapis" and uses the same conventions, and it gets included along with your code... then you get all sorts of headaches anyway like module name collisions!